# How to remove or throw sign of [ from javascript

Tags: javascript

i am new in javascript and make some project but still have little bit obstackle.

How can we remove or throw the character the '[' and ']' ( to the first and last ) from this data collection :

```
[ [ '9C65F9211010', -65.62, '#b87333' ],
[ '9C65F9211R33 , -90.23, '#b87909' ],
[ '9C65F9210E43', -73.46, '#b87333' ] ]
```

so, the result that i mean become :

```
[ '9C65F9211010', -65.62, '#b87333' ],
[ '9C65F9211R33 , -90.23, '#b87909' ],
[ '9C65F9210E43', -73.46, '#b87333' ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it an array? If so just use `arr[0]`.

Comment: i already try, but the result become [ '9C65F9211010', -65.62, '#b87333' ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming source date is a String, the code can be something like:

```js
var str = "[ [ '9C65F9211010', -65.62, '#b87333' ],\n"+
"[ '9C65F9211R33 , -90.23, '#b87909' ],\n"+
"[ '9C65F9210E43', -73.46, '#b87333' ] ]";

if ((str.substring(0,2) == '[ ') && (str.substring(str.length - 2) == ' ]')){
  document.write("<pre>");
  var strNew = str.substr(2, str.length-4);
  console.log(strNew)
}
```

Assuming source is array:

```js
const arr = [ [ '9C65F9211010', -65.62, '#b87333' ],
[ '9C65F9211R33' , -90.23, '#b87909' ],
[ '9C65F9210E43', -73.46, '#b87333' ] ];

str = "["+arr.join ("],\n[")+"]";
console.log(str);
```